# How to create a vector with r

Tags: vector, character, assign

Good evening everyone.
I'm trying to run this script vc<-c("Paris", "Rome", "Strasbourg")
but I get this error message.
I would like to understand why and how to correct it.
Please help me

I would like to create a vc vector containing the names of the cities Paris, Rome and Madrid.